# Is there a BNF,ENBF standard?

Tags: bnf, ebnf

I found a lot of information about BNF and EBNF on Google, but they are not uniform, so I want to ask if there are any standards for BNF and EBNF?

Comment: Off the top of my head, no, there isn't. And even if there is a standard, I'm pretty sure it isn't much used, or else the standard descriptions of various standardized programming languages wouldn't be using such a variety of ways to describe language syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any BNF standards but there is ISO EBNF https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-14977.pdf